# Debug DNS time out for Nginx application deployed on Azure VM

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, azure, gunicorn

I have an application deployed on an Azure VM using an Nginx web server. The application uses supervisor to set up the Nginx and gunicorn servers. I have checked all configuration and log files and all seems to be working OK. However when I point a browser at the website the browser times out for the www.mydomain.com and for mydomain.com returns:

```
This site can’t be reached
mydomain.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
```

On Azure I have set up a DNS zone containing:

```
Name: @ TYPE: NS TTL: 120 VALUE: relevant azure name servers.
Name: www TYPE: CAME TTL 60 mydomain.com
```

On the domain registrar I have set the DNS names as per the azure DNS names.

On my local machine I have:

Flushed the cache on the browser.
checked nslookup www.mydomain.com

```
Server:         127.0.1.1
Address:        127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: www.mydomain.com
Address: xxx.xxx.xx.xx
```

tried traceroute, xxx.msn.net addresses were located without any [closed] so I presume the server was found.

tried:

```
host -t A www.mydomain.com
>>www.mydomian.com is an alias for mydomain.themsazureaddress.com
>>mydomain.themsazureaddress.com has address xxx.xxx.xx.xx
```

On the web server I have:

tried netcat:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:https                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:8000          *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:6379          *:*                     LISTEN
```

and netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      62133/nginx     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      62133/nginx
```

checked the nginx config:

```
upstream app_server_wsgiapp {  
     server localhost:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {  
 listen 80;
 server_name myapp.com; 
 rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}

server {  
  server_name           myapp.com;
  listen                443 ssl;
```

Checked nginx error and access logs:

access logs are empty, error log just contains:

```
epoll add event: fd:11 op:1 ev:00000001
```

I also checked processes and supervisor, gunicorn, redis, celery are all running OK. I am just using sqlite so I don't need to worry about the database setup.

Any other suggestions for dubugging why I cant see the application?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the domain in question.

Comment: From all your info, I couldn´t find anything about your nsg/firewall configuration. Another question, what is your Linux distribution?

Comment: @BrunoFaria Adding port 80 and 443 in/out rules to the nsg worked, I had no idea about Azure NSG's. Please add this as an answer and I will accept

Comment: The problem lies somewhere between your client computer and the DNS settings. You get a time-out trying to resolve the DNS name, so at that stage you didn't try to contact your Azure deployment yet. If the issue reappears I'd recommend doing some DNS troubleshooting locally (fire up wireshark to take a trace, try some manual nslookup, maybe try from another place like www.digwebinterface.com .. etc)

Comment: @DonSmythe great! A simple fix to a big problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSG was missing in the user VM configuration.

> A network security group (NSG) contains a list of access control list
>   (ACL) rules that allow or deny network traffic to your VM instances in
>   a Virtual Network.
>
> NSGs can be associated with either subnets or individual VM instances
>   within that subnet. When a NSG is associated with a subnet, the ACL
>   rules apply to all the VM instances in that subnet. In addition,
>   traffic to an individual VM can be restricted further by associating a
>   NSG directly to that VM.

Configuring NSGs in Azure Portal:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal